# ¿Cómo incluir archivo javascript dentro de php?

Tags: php, javascript

Lo que quiero es que cuando llegue a la condición de 'else' lea el archivo cart_2.js, le he intentado de esta manera:

```
<?php
 sleep(1);
 include_once '../connections/conexion.php';
 if($_REQUEST) {

if(isset($_POST['product_quantity']) && ($_POST['product_id'])) {

    $product_id =         $_REQUEST['product_id'];
    $product_quantity =   $_REQUEST['product_quantity'];

    $stock   = $ConexionBD->query("SELECT unidadesExistentes FROM articulo 
                WHERE idArticulo = '$product_id' ");

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($stock)) {
        $valor = $rows['unidadesExistentes'];


        if($valor < $product_quantity ){
            echo '<div id="Error">Sin stock</div>';

        }else {
            //aqui esta mi archivo .js, creo que no lo esta leyendo
            echo "<script languaje='javascript'  src='../js/cart_2.js'>";
        }
    }

} //end isset

 } //end REQUEST

>?
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer que lea el archivo .js?

Comment: Hermann, que es lo que quieres lograr? Te lo pregunto porque creo que estas mal en tu pensamiento logico. PHP es el lenguaje en tu servidor. Deberias de dar una respuesta con PHP y del lado del cliente, que es javascript, obtener una respuesta y hacer algo con esa respuesta. Me imagino que ese "algo" es lo que hace tu archivo cart_2.js. Asi que tienes que mantener lo de javascript del lado de javascript y lo de php del lado de php.

Comment: Opino igual que @Kenny Algo esta mal con tu pensamiento y lo que quieres realizar.

Comment: Porque no te pasas unos minutos por el [chat] y puedes preguntar alli, creo que quizas te seria de mas ayuda.

Comment: Aunque es posible embeber html y javascript en Php, eso dificulta el mantenimineto y escalabilidad del código, lo hace difícil de leer y es más propenso a bugs. Estoy de acuerdo con @Kenny, deberías dejarlos separados y con JS hacer una petición a PHP, consulta AJAX y XMLHttpRequest de JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está el src, vale, pero ¿no tienes dentro de ese cart_2.js alguna función que lo tengas que llamar desde este php? Prueba meter ese javascript en una función para así una vez enlazada en el head, puedas llamar mediante la función dentro de un contexto html como en el ejemplo.

Prueba esto a ver...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cart_2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
 sleep(1);
 include_once '../connections/conexion.php';
 if($_REQUEST) {

if(isset($_POST['product_quantity']) && ($_POST['product_id'])) {

    $product_id =         $_REQUEST['product_id'];
    $product_quantity =   $_REQUEST['product_quantity'];

    $stock   = $ConexionBD->query("SELECT unidadesExistentes FROM articulo 
                WHERE idArticulo = '$product_id' ");

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($stock)) {
        $valor = $rows['unidadesExistentes'];


        if($valor < $product_quantity ){
            echo '<div id="Error">Sin stock</div>';

        }else {
            //AQUÍ SEGUIDO DEBERÍAS PONER LA LLAMADA A LA FUNCIÓN
            echo "onload='funciónjavascript()'";
        }
    }

} //end isset

 } //end REQUEST

>?

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: el archivo PHP es llamado dentro de un BODY, es decir lo tengo antes del cierre del BODY

Comment: el simple alert tampoco te funciona, ¿verdad? ¿lo has probado?

Comment: Si me muestra el alert